# How to get certain properties of the array from Model to ViewModel without Json parseerror (Asp.Net Core MVC)

Tags: json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, automapper

I'm currently working on the Asp.Net Core MVC project and have the following Message class

```
public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SenderId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SenderId")]
    public virtual User Sender { get; set; }

    public string RecipientId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RecipientId")]

    public virtual User Recipient { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public bool IsRead { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateRead { get; set; }
    public DateTime MessageSent { get; set; }
    public bool SenderDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool RecipientDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Using the mapper, I get the below ViewModel for the Message review:

```
public class MessageReviewViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string SenderId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SenderId")]
    public virtual User Sender { get; set; }

    public string RecipientId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RecipientId")]
    public virtual User Recipient { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }
    public bool IsRead { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateRead { get; set; }
    public DateTime MessageSent { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I would like to get actually the Recipient and Sender users, however the reason I have such a simple MessageReviewViewModel is because I'm getting the list of this view models and with this users json throws an error & without it I have successfull result.
However, the problem is, that for the proper display in the Inbox view I still need the certain properties of Recipient and Sender user's (their main photo url, username & etc).

My mapper configuration is as below to get the messages from the repository:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MessageReviewViewModel>> GetMessagesForUserByUserId(string userId)
    {
        var messages = await messageRepository.GetMessagesForUser(userId);
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Message, MessageReviewViewModel>();
            cfg.IgnoreUnmapped();
        });
        IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        var messageList = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Message>, IEnumerable<MessageReviewViewModel>>(messages);
        return messageList;
    }
```

In the react component (I have integrated react.js in the asp.net core mvc) once it did mount I make a get request to get the messages list as below and setState messagesList to the received array.

```
    componentDidMount() {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', "/Messages/GetMessages", true);
    xhr.onload = () => {
        const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        this.setState({ messagesList: data });
        console.log(this.state.messagesList);
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

And this is the action in the controller, that is being called:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetMessages()
    {
        var userFromRepo = await  userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
        var messages = await messagesService.GetMessagesForUserByUserId(userFromRepo.Id);
        var sortedMessageList = messages.OrderByDescending(m => m.MessageSent);
        return Json(sortedMessageList);
    }
```

As I mentioned, it all works without any problem unless there are no virtual User Sender and virtual User Recipient in the MessageReviewViewModel. Once I have them in code, this is the error I get:

[image: error_snapshot]

Probably it is worth to mention, that the User class objects (in my scenario Sender & Recipient for example) also have the virtual properties inside and I thought that it may be problem for Json parse these objects, which have other objects as property.
Could you please advise how I can include these properties in the ViewModel so neither mapper nor JSON throw any error? I'm okay even to get only selected properties of the obje (for example just string username, mainphoto url & etc).
It is also ok, if there is any Json method, that will solve this parseError with virtual users included in the ViewModel

Comment: What have you tried so far? How does your mapping look like? What's the error?

Comment: @ChristophLütjen thanks for the interest, please have a look, I have updated the post, hope this is more informative. If any additional data is required, please let me know.

Comment: I guess the reason for your JSON parse error is, that your server does not return JSON at all but some kind of error page. How does the response look like? You can see that in your browsers developer console > network tab or you could add `console.log(xhr.responseText)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after finding that mapper can also be configured to the level that is required by the user

The Message model is as below as previously

```
    public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SenderId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SenderId")]
    public virtual User Sender { get; set; }

    public string RecipientId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RecipientId")]
    public virtual User Recipient { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public bool IsRead { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateRead { get; set; }
    public DateTime MessageSent { get; set; }
    public bool SenderDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool RecipientDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

And the MessageReviewViewModel changed to below:

```
    public class MessageReviewViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SenderId { get; set; }
    public string SenderUsername { get; set; }
    public string SenderMainPhotoUrl { get; set; }
    public string RecipientId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RecipientId")]
    public string RecipientUsername { get; set; }
    public string RecipientMainPhotoUrl { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public bool IsRead { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateRead { get; set; }
    public DateTime MessageSent { get; set; }
}
```

Only for the mapper the configuration was required as below:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MessageReviewViewModel>> GetMessagesForUserByUserId(string userId)
    {
        var messages = await messageRepository.GetMessagesForUser(userId);
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Message, MessageReviewViewModel>()
            .ForMember(destination=>destination.RecipientUsername,map=>map.MapFrom(
                source=>source.Recipient.UserName)) //gets only string for username instead of whole User model
            .ForMember(destination=> destination.RecipientMainPhotoUrl,map=>map.MapFrom(
                source=>source.Recipient.MainProfilePicture)) //gets only string for profile picture instead of whole User model
            .ForMember(destination=>destination.SenderUsername,map=>map.MapFrom(
                source=>source.Sender.UserName))
            .ForMember(destination=>destination.SenderMainPhotoUrl,map=>map.MapFrom(
                source=>source.Sender.MainProfilePicture)); 
            cfg.IgnoreUnmapped();
        });
        IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        var messageList = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Message>, IEnumerable<MessageReviewViewModel>>(messages);
        return messageList;
    }
```

As all received data now are only strings, Json has no problem parsing it